# Getting Unterminated object exception for JSON array

Tags: php, android, arrays, json, jsonexception

I am getting an array of JSON from server. But I am trying to access it I am getting the Unterminated object exception.

I checked the output for any comma missed or wrong syntax but still not working.

JSON array

```
    [
  {
    "cust_id": "8",
    "mer_id": "3",
    "fav": "1",
    "cont_name": "sandeep",
    "kirana_name": "kasar",
    "phone_no": "9422879610",
    "email_id": "kasar1@gmail.com",
    "address": "nashik"
  },
  {
    "cust_id": "8",
    "mer_id": "1",
    "fav": "1",
    "cont_name": "sandeep",
    "kirana_name": "general store",
    "phone_no": "1212345623",
    "email_id": "kasar@gmail.com",
    "address": "nashik road nashik"
  },
  {
    "cust_id": "8",
    "mer_id": "5",
    "fav": "0",
    "cont_name": "a",
    "kirana_name": "s",
    "phone_no": "9422879610",
    "email_id": "sam@gmail.com",
    "address": "aa"
  },
  {
    "cust_id": "8",
    "mer_id": "6",
    "fav": "0",
    "cont_name": "see ya",
    "kirana_name": "see ya kirana",
    "phone_no": "8698766460",
    "email_id": "deepmalasingh55@gmail.com",
    "address": "dee"
  },
  {
    "cust_id": "8",
    "mer_id": "5",
    "fav": "0",
    "cont_name": "a",
    "kirana_name": "s",
    "phone_no": "9422879610",
    "email_id": "sam@gmail.com",
    "address": "aa"
  },
  {
    "cust_id": "8",
    "mer_id": "9",
    "fav": "0",
    "cont_name": "fre",
    "kirana_name": "fee kirana",
    "phone_no": "8698766460",
    "email_id": "deepmalasinghop@gmail.com",
    "address": "plotno:12,sahaydri nagar"
  }
]
```

Retrieving data from array :

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            merchantsList.clear();
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("array");
            if(jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (jsonObject.has("message")) {
                        String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        snackbar.show();
                    } else {
                        long id,merchant_id,item_quantity;
                        String kirana_name,created_at,address;
                        int fav;

                         merchant_id=jsonObject.getLong("mer_id");
                        kirana_name=jsonObject.getString("kirana_name");

                        fav=jsonObject.getInt("fav");
                        address=jsonObject.getString("address");


                        Merchants merchants = new Merchants(merchant_id,kirana_name,address,fav);
                        merchantsList.add(merchants);
                        merchantsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }

            }
```

exception :

```
    org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 973 of {"array":[{"cust_id":"8","mer_id":"3","fav":"1","cont_name":"sandeep","kirana_name":"kasar","phone_no":"9422879610","email_id":"kasar1@gmail.com","address":"nashik"},{"cust_id":"8","mer_id":"1","fav":"1","cont_name":"sandeep","kirana_name":"general store","phone_no":"1212345623","email_id":"kasar@gmail.com","address":"nashik road nashik"},{"cust_id":"8","mer_id":"5","fav":"0","cont_name":"a","kirana_name":"s","phone_no":"9422879610","email_id":"sam@gmail.com","address":"aa"},{"cust_id":"8","mer_id":"6","fav":"0","cont_name":"see ya","kirana_name":"see ya kirana","phone_no":"8698766460","email_id":"deepmalasingh55@gmail.com","address":"dee"},{"cust_id":"8","mer_id":"5","fav":"0","cont_name":"a","kirana_name":"s","phone_no":"9422879610","email_id":"sam@gmail.com","address":"aa"},{"cust_id":"8","mer_id":"9","fav":"0","cont_name":"fre","kirana_name":"fee kirana","phone_no":"8698766460","email_id":"deepmalasinghop@gmail.com","address":"plotno:12,sahaydri nagar"}]895da9a9a4cdd0825848479ee7e6c7ed2}
11-28 10:23:52.302 27004-27069/com.kiranaapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
```

What's going wrong?? Any help will be great..Than you..

Comment: *What's going wrong?* Your json is wrong ... And no, it is not the same json as you wrote in the question

Comment: @Sid The Json you posted in code is completely different from the json in the Logcat so the  [json is invalid](http://i.imgur.com/tHJ6Gg8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is because your Json array contains invalid string at the end. 
this is the string.
**895da9a9a4cdd0825848479ee7e6c7ed2**
Remove this and try again.

**EDIT**

You can check it by yourself. Go to this site [Json Parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) and then paste your Json array there. Then you can notice an error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such element like `"array"` in your JSON, which you are using it. JSON should have some key for each value.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("array");
```

Here in this case you array of JSON should have `"array"=[]`